# How to do IF statement for the final character in a cell (VBA)

Tags: vba, if-statement

I am using the current code

```
If Left(cell.Value, 1) = ")" Then

....

End If
```

But it still seems to apply to every cell, not just the cells ending with `")"`

Any help would be great ( I am still a noob)

Comment: VBA also has a `Right()` function. In any event, without more of a [mcve] it is hard to say much. I have no idea what you mean by "it still seems to apply to every cell" -- your code isn't applying it to *any* cell.

Comment: More than one Office application has a `cell` object - which application are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the `Right()` function

---

If we test `Left()` & `Right()` on the string `Stack` we get....

1. `Left(String, 1) = S`
2. `Left(String, 2) = St`
3. `Right(String, 1) = k`
4. `Right(String, 2) = ck`

Since you are interested in the last character you want the first character starting from the right, not the left. Therefore, you should use...

```
If Right(Cell, 1) = ")" Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

Comment: Also: `Left` and `Right` both take and return a `Variant`; their little-known twins `Left$` and `Right$` take and return a `String` and should arguably be preferred.